# Why are xml transformations needed?

Tags: .net, xml

What is basic need of xml transformation? In which situation we can use this ? can we use this  in .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you get several different product catalogues, each in a different XML format.

You use yet another XML format internally.

The simplest thing to do is transform the different XML formats to your own. You can use XSLT for that.

The .NET framework has extensive support from XSL transformations - see the [System.Xml.Xsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.aspx) namespace.

Comment: *NB* .NET supports XSLT V1. There is also XSLT V2 (and has been for a few years) that makes many common tasks easier. Be careful with non-.NET specific examples of XSLT as they might assume V2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with data in XML format, you sooner or later need that data in a different format, need parts of it extracted, need it converted to HTML, simple text, another XML format etc. That's what [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) is for. XSLT is a complete programming language. If you want to see some examples for the capabilities, look at the [docbook XSL site](http://wiki.docbook.org/topic/DocBookXslStylesheets).

However, sometimes it easier / more convenient to process your XML by other techniques. For example, in .NET you will also find the `System.Xml.XmlDocument` class, which allows you to process XML data in another way, without using XSLT.